# Сохранение настроек меню приложения

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qsettings

В окне есть меню. В меню есть вложенное меню. Во вложенном меню есть три действия, которые объедены в `QActionGroup`.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь поменял настройки в меню, при выходе из приложения и снова при входе в приложение они **`сохранялись`**, чтобы пользователь опять их не настраивал. 
Буду очень благодарен !

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, action_search_options_1 = None, action_search_options_2 = None, 
                action_search_options_3 = None):
        
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # берём из функции create_menuBar QAction для работы с файлом window_1
        self.action_search_options_1 = action_search_options_1
        self.action_search_options_2 = action_search_options_2
        self.action_search_options_3 = action_search_options_3


        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() # создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()

    def create_page(self):

        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        # создание обьектов
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к генерации паролей")

        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)
        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)


        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает
    
    def create_menuBar(self):

        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)
        
        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1) # добавление в меню опции

        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)

        # добавляем в окно
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

Вроде всё правильно сделал для сохранения настроек, сам файл создаётся, я настройки не сохраняются, что может быть не так в коде?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QSettings

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # создание файла для сохранения натроек
        self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() # создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()
        self.load_settings()

    def create_page(self):

        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        # создание обьектов
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к генерации паролей")

        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)
        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)

        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает

    def create_menuBar(self):

        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)

        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1) # добавление в меню опции

        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)

        # добавляем в окно  
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        # возращаем значения
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_1.isChecked()))
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_2.isChecked()))
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_3.isChecked()))

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        self.action_search_options_2.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        self.action_search_options_3.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вы пытались изучить и попробовать `QSettings`, который вам рекомендовали в предыдущем вопросе?

Comment: Ни как не получается, всё перепробовал, пойду ещё по изучаю

Comment: По изучайте,  попробуйте и если не получится,  опубликуйте тот пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QSettings::setValue(const QString &key, const QVariant &value)
>
> Устанавливает значение установочного ключа на значение.
>
> Если ключ уже существует, предыдущее значение будет перезаписано. Обратите внимание, что в реестре Windows и файлах INI используются ключи без учета регистра, в то время как API-интерфейс CFPreferences в macOS и iOS использует ключи с учетом регистра. Чтобы избежать проблем с переносимостью, ознакомьтесь с правилами раздела и синтаксиса ключа.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import QSettings

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # создание файла для сохранения натроек
        self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()
        self.load_settings()

    def create_page(self):
        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # создание обьектов
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к генерации паролей")

        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)
        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)

        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает

    def create_menuBar(self):
        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)

        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1) # добавление в меню опции

        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)

        # добавляем в окно  
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        # возращаем значения
#        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_1.isChecked()))
#        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_2.isChecked()))
#        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_3.isChecked()))

        settings.setValue('BoolValue1', int(self.action_search_options_1.isChecked()))      # BoolValue1
        settings.setValue('BoolValue2', int(self.action_search_options_2.isChecked()))      # BoolValue2
        settings.setValue('BoolValue3', int(self.action_search_options_3.isChecked()))      # BoolValue3

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

#        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
#        self.action_search_options_2.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
#        self.action_search_options_3.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))

        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue1', 0)))) # BoolValue1
        self.action_search_options_2.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue2', 0)))) # BoolValue2
        self.action_search_options_3.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue3', 0)))) # BoolValue3

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде всё правильно сделал для сохранения настроек, сам файл создаётся, я настройки не сохраняются, что может быть не так в коде

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QSettings

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # создание файла для сохранения натроек
        self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() # создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()
        self.load_settings()

    def create_page(self):

        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        # создание обьектов
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к генерации паролей")

        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_2)
        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)
        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)

        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает

    def create_menuBar(self):

        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)

        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1) # добавление в меню опции

        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)

        # добавляем в окно  
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        # возращаем значения
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_1.isChecked()))
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_2.isChecked()))
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.action_search_options_3.isChecked()))

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(self.CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        self.action_search_options_2.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        self.action_search_options_3.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```